# How to list pages in Silverlight Application?

Tags: silverlight

I want to list all pages in application and create instance of these pages programatically. If you have any idea about this please help. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a Silverlight Navigation application?

If you need to get all types that inherit from System.Windows.Controls.Page in your app you can use:

```
var pageTypes = typeof(App)
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(type => typeof(Page).IsAssignableFrom(type));
```

Then you can iterate over this to get instances of each:

```
var instances = types.Select(type => Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```